# Why is viewWillAppear: called twice when my view controller is initially displayed?

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have an iOS 7 app with a side hamburger menu and a main table view controller where I display content. Whenever the user selects an item in my side menu, I'm hiding the side menu and I want to reload data in the main view controller. My initial thought was to put my data refreshing code in my main view controller's `viewWillAppear`:

But when I set a breakpoint in `viewWillAppear:`, I get 2 calls when the view controller initially appears, one from `UIViewController` itself, and another from `[ECSlidingViewController viewWillAppear:]` where the following line seems to call my `viewWillAppear:` again

```
[self.topViewController beginAppearanceTransition:YES animated:animated];
```

On the other hand, when I show the left menu and then hide it, my view controller's `viewWillAppear:` is not called this time, so data is not refreshed in my case.

Did I miss something in my configuration somewhere? Is that a bug or a feature? How should I use it?

PS: I used to use `IIViewDeckController` and I had the exact same problem, so I switched to `ECSlidingViewController` because it said that "Your view controllers will receive the appropriate view life cycle and rotation methods at the right time.".

Comment: May be https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu will helps you

Comment: I experience exactly the same behavior. Is there other solution besides using another library?

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, I managed to do what I wanted with another library: https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

I had to implement delegate methods in order to call lifecycle methods on my view controller when menu is shown or hidden:

```
- (void)sideMenu:(RESideMenu *)sideMenu willShowMenuViewController:(UIViewController *)menuViewController {
    [sideMenu.contentViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
}

- (void)sideMenu:(RESideMenu *)sideMenu didShowMenuViewController:(UIViewController *)menuViewController {
    [sideMenu.contentViewController viewDidDisappear:YES];
}

- (void)sideMenu:(RESideMenu *)sideMenu willHideMenuViewController:(UIViewController *)menuViewController {
    [sideMenu.contentViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
}

- (void)sideMenu:(RESideMenu *)sideMenu didHideMenuViewController:(UIViewController *)menuViewController {
    [sideMenu.contentViewController viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

And viewWillAppear is not called twice initially.

Comment: Just FYI, I think you shouldn't call those viewWill/Did methods directly. Call something like `beginAppearanceTransition:NO animated:YES`